# in my client app , we maintain a database when ever the table is updated need to receive notification from firebase notification to all the device

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried to send msg in firebase console but client requires to generate notification automatically if the table in the database is modified

is there any ways i can make it happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) in combination with firebase functions and [firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events). What you want to happen is actually the first use case described in the documentation for [firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases):

[image: Picture taken from firebase documentation]

The picture is straight from the firebase documentation.

Comment: my excel file is maintained in the microsoft sharepoint, we access the files through sharepoint API , it that excel is updated we need to trigger a firebase notification from the backend of flutter application